# Give a TabItem Focus when Dynamically Adding Using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabitem

All, I am adding a `TabItem` to a `TabControl` dynamically using MVVM. The new `TabItems` load fine, but I want the added tab to gain focus automatically. That is, I add a tab and I do not want to have to click on that tab to give it focus.

The XAML for the `TabControl` look like

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Workspaces}" 
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            TabStripPlacement="Top">
<TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="TabItem">
      <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"/>
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
      <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
   </Style>
</TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <views:ResourceControl DataContext="{Binding}" 
                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
   </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

I thought (based upon some answers here), that `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` would solve this for me, but this is not working.

How can I auto-select the added `TabItem`?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the selectedIndex to a property on your viewmodel

```
SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex}" >
```

or use

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedWorkSpace}"
```

In your ViewModel, when you add a new *Workspace* to *Workspaces*, set the SelectedTabIndex/SelectedWorkSpace appropriately.

The later gives you access to the current workspace which you will probably need anyway.

Comment: +1 Thanks you. However, what is `SelectedTabindex` here? Do I have to create a property in the relevant view model?

Comment: I think it would be better to bind to SelectedItem (not SelectedIndex).

Comment: @grantnz, perhaps yes. I had used SelectedIndex earlier which worked I have to see if SelectedItem works. maybe Killercam can let us know

Comment: @cheedep, I use SelectedItem binding with tab controls as it seems a more natural property to have on the view model than the index into a collection.  Probably doesn't make much difference either way.

Comment: Very true, I will update the answer. I had used the SelectedIndex when I was binding to an Enum property on the Viewmodel using a converter.