# How to bind TabItem GotFocus to ViewModel comand

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I have a silverlight app that uses a form with a TabControl.

I'd like to have one of the TabItem GotFocus events to bind to my ViewModel. However I am getting errors when I do the following.

```
<controls:TabControl>
  <controls.TabItem GotFocus="{Binding Model.MyGotFocusCommand}">
```

Can I bind the TabControl events to my ViewModel?

Comment: have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659592/give-a-tabitem-focus-when-dynamically-adding-using-mvvm

Comment: `Model.MyGotFocusCommand` well, that's a code smell.  Cramming UI logic into your models and view models, eh?

Answer (score 2):

You can not bind an event directly to a command. Invoking a command on an event requires the use of the Expression Blend interaction triggers.

Add references to the Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll and System.Windows.Interactivity.dll assemblies.

Declare the interactivity and interactions namespace prefixes in your view:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

and then:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GotFocusCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

If you dislike the use of Expression Blend you can go with a framework (e.g. MVVM Light) which allows binding via a behavior. This is exposed via an EventToCommand class as a Behavior that allows you to bind an event to a command. This way, the bound command is invoked like an event handler when the event is raised.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay,Path=GotFocusCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Last but not least I often find it acceptable to simply catch the event in the code behind and from there I route it into my view model. If you can live with the drawbacks (mainly loss of testability) that approach is easy and straightforward.